# How to remove duplicates in the az command output using --query

Tags: json, azure-cli, jmespath

Command
`az resource list --resource-group MYRG --query "[].{type:type}"`

output

```
[
{
"type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces"
},
{
"type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces"
},
{
"type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups"
},
{
"type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups"
}
]
```

Tried below command but no luck

$ az resource list  --resource-group MYRG --query [? type == `"Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"`]
bash: Microsoft.Web/serverFarms: No such file or directory
argument --query: invalid jmespath_type value: '[?'
To learn more about --query, please visit: 'https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/query-azure-cli'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> az resource list --resource-group MYRG --query "[].{type:type}"

you might have multiple resources of same resource type under the specific resource group would suggest you to list the resources by  adding another filter like name & type as shown in the below & check the cmdlet is giving any duplicate values

```
az resource list --resource-group <resource-groupname> --query "[].{type:type,name:name}"
```

> $ az resource list --resource-group MYRG --query [? type == `"Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"`]

looks like there is an syntactical error in the above command   can you try the below command to list resource which are of type 'Microsoft.Web/serverFarms' under a resource group.

```
az resource list --resource-group <resource-groupname> --query "[?type == 'Microsoft.Web/serverFarms'].{name:name,type:type}"`
```

Here is the reference document to [filter the array using AzureCLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli#filter-arrays)

**Note**: In JMESPath, strings are always surrounded by single quotes ('). If you use double quotes as part of a string in a filter predicate, you'll get empty output.